# Managing SSH keys within Jenkins for Git

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to get Jenkins up and running with a GitHub hosted repository (using the Jenkins Git plugin). The repository has multiple git submodules, so I'm not sure I want to try and manage multiple deploy keys.

My personal GitHub user account is a collaborator of each of the projects I wish to pull in with Jenkins, so I've generated an SSH key within `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh` and added it to my personal GitHub account.

However, when I try and add the repository URL to my Jenkins project configuration, I get:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@github.com:***/***.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed. 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Likewise, when I schedule a build I get:

```
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've also tried setting up an SSH config file as outlined [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130502014020/blog.firmhouse.com/configuring-multiple-private-ssh-deploy-keys-in-jenkins-for-github-com), but to no avail.

Can anyone shed any light? Thanks

**EDIT**

I should add that I'm running CentOS 5.8

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It looks like the `github.com` host which jenkins tries to connect to is not listed under the Jenkins user's `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts`. Jenkins runs on most distros as the user `jenkins` and hence has its own `.ssh` directory to store the list of public keys and `known_hosts`.

The easiest solution I can think of to fix this problem is:

```
# Login as the jenkins user and specify shell explicity,
# since the default shell is /bin/false for most
# jenkins installations.
sudo su jenkins -s /bin/bash

cd SOME_TMP_DIR
# git clone YOUR_GITHUB_URL

# Allow adding the SSH host key to your known_hosts

# Exit from su
exit
```

Comment: @Adam - You never mentioned about the `known_hosts` ;) You were only talking about the `id_rsa.pub` public key :D

Comment: I did. (*Often times you see failure if the host has not been added or authorized*). I just did not mention explicitly the file.

Comment: Anyways you beat me to it, while I was formatting the answer :D

Comment: Thanks for both your replies ;) I thought it might be something to do with known hosts, but I'm unable to login as jenkins. I managed to set a password for the user and I get a password prompt but the user session isn't switched when I provide it. Is there a way to manually add github as a known_host?

Comment: @James when you `sudo` its whatever the user your logged in as password and not the jenkins password. So you'll need a sudo user or even easier login as root and then run the sudo command.

Comment: If you're running as `root` (say using sudo), you should be able to switch to any other user using the `su` command without any password. you can just do `echo $HOME` or `whoami` to confirm this.

Comment: Indeed, I am logged in as root. `su jenkins` does nothing; I'm still root@servername. `echo $HOME` gives me `/root`

Comment: What does `su - jenkins` do ?

Comment: @Tuxdude this does the same as I mentioned above. It might help to mention that I'm able to `passwd jenkins` without issue, so I find it odd that I can't login

Comment: I think I know the issue. Run this command: `usermod -s '/bin/bash' jenkins` to set the shell as `/bin/bash` instead of the default `/bin/false` that gets set for the jenkins user. Then you should be able to `su`.

Comment: Perfect. That's worked; I'm now getting a git config error (haven't set it for Jenkins). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just realized `su` has an option to specify shell, so that you don't need to run `usermod`, have updated the answer :)

Comment: Minor tweak: `sudo su -l jenkins -s /bin/bash`

`-l` drops you into the `jenkins` user home directory and sets the login environment variables. In some environments, this might be necessary for like `LD_PATH`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have searched this forever. Went through many blogs but no luck. This line did it: sudo su jenkins -s /bin/bash. Why nobody else mention this critical command? This is the only thing I did not do, so much time wasted.

Comment: When I try to `git clone` under `jenkins` user I get `error fatal: could not create work tree dir '<name>'.: Permission denied`

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried logging in as the jenkins user?

Try this:

```
sudo -i -u jenkins #For RedHat you might have to do 'su' instead.
git clone git@github.com:your/repo.git
```

Often times you see failure if the host has not been added or authorized (hence I always manually login as hudson/jenkins for the first connection to github/bitbucket) but that link you included supposedly fixes that.

If the above doesn't work try recopying the key. Make sure its the pub key (ie id_rsa.pub). Maybe you missed some characters?

Answer (score 4):

According to this [article](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey), you may try following command:

```
   ssh-add -l
```

If your key isn't in the list, then

```
   ssh-add /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa_project
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me if you have config and the private key file in the */Jenkins/.ssh/* you need to **chown** (change owner) for these 2 files then **restart** jenkins in order for the jenkins instance to read these 2 files.