# jenkins failed to connect to remote bit bucket repository

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am using jenkins and trying to connect to the bit bucket remote repository for that I provide the bit bucket URL in source code management in git repositories, I create the credentials also for that bit bucket account added in the credentials

I tried the below in git repositories

```
https://nagarjun123@bitbucket.org/gsmohan/quickride.git
```

But it gives the error below specified:

> ERROR:Failed to connect to repository : Failed to connect to https://nagarjun123@bitbucket.org/gsmohan/quickride.git using credentials bitbucket account (status = 401)

Can anyone please help to me?

Comment: I guess you mistyped the password. Status 401 is Unauthorized.

Comment: I have used both https and ssh authentication in Jenkins w/Bitbucket and never needed to encode the password in the URL. Double-checking the password in your credentials is a good idea; otherwise the best bet is to generate ssh keys and use them for your authentication (using the ssh form of the URL). Atlassian has complete help on ssh setup - https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket and this post has some info on the jenkins side of the setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314760/managing-ssh-keys-within-jenkins-for-git

Answer (score 23):

Change repository address to this format:

```
https://user:password@bitbucket.org/user/project_name.git
```

And of course:

- user - your bitbucket user,
- password- your bitbucket password,
- project_name - name of project/repo,

Comment: At last, after a few days of back and forth!

Comment: but this leaves your password in plain text. A better way is to use SSH and private key.

Comment: Before going this route, just make sure you aren't a dumby, and check if git is installed on your server. I had made the mistake, and thought git was already installed on the server...it wasn't.

Answer (score 7):

In Jenkins ver. 2.6 just use

```
https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project_name.git
```

And add your credentials.

[image]
**Important:** Make sure that your git installed version is greater or equals than `1.7.4` because of the `--local` issue.

If you are on CentOS maybe you face the same problem than me. Here is a great [answer from @AmirHd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820716/4848308) to upgrade git version on CentOS, if you already have git installed just type:

```
yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras update git
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use that structure :

```
git@CREDENTIALS:BUCKET_TEAM/BUCKET_REPO.git
```

Questions :
How many credentials do you have ?
If you have more than one, you should clearly setup them within your server

Be carefull ! Jenkins when adding SSh keys **DOES NOT accept passphrases**

check your ssh keys within **$HOME/.ssh/config** and **$HOME/.ssh/know_host** of **jenkins** user (if jenkins is a service) or your application server user

One last point, **YOU MUST** first login with your jenkins user using SSH before enabling jenkins sync with git with a ssh git@bitbucket.org

Comment: Hey guys, thank you in advance for telling me what is incorrect in my reply.
I have faced lots of issue concerning JENKINS specially with authentication of multiple CREDENTIALS.