# Execute command as passwordless user

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

To access a git repository from Jenkins, I need to login as this user and execute some commands (according to e.g. http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/labs/configuring-jenkins-continuous-integration-server-to-work-with-git/, [Jenkins Host key verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174194/jenkins-host-key-verification-failed) or [Managing SSH keys within Jenkins for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314760/managing-ssh-keys-within-jenkins-for-git), I need to accept the host to known hosts and generate an ssh-key. I created the key with the root user, and added credentials to jenkins - it does not work, and therefore I assume it is still the wrong known hosts). But everytime I do `su jenkins`, the following appears:

```
reichelt@aspra4:~$ su jenkins
No passwd entry for user 'jenkins'
```

Even the solution recommended here: [how to run script as another user without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password) does respond the same thing:

```
reichelt@aspra4:~$ su -c "git ls-remote -h ... HEAD" -s /bin/sh jenkins
No passwd entry for user 'jenkins'
```

But nevertheless, I need to connect somehow to the server. Does anybody has an hint how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user called Jenkins using adduser or whatever the command is for your unix.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem, My solution to this problem is add jenkins to sudo list and change it's password

Code:

```
sudo adduser jenkins sudo

passwd jenkins
```

Now next time you do su jenkins it should work.