# Store GitHub credentials on Windows with Git Bash

Tags: git, github, jenkins, git-bash

I am trying to set up a Jenkins Windows slave which will pull from GitHub using Git Bash. I have installed Git Bash on my Windows server so it is available through the Windows command prompt. When I try to invoke any Git command that goes to GitHub it always asks for my credentials.

How can I set this up so it does not ask for my credentials?

Points to note:

I am testing it by invoking from the Windows cmd and not the Git Bash shell as I believe this is how Jenkins will call it.

If it isn't possible, how do you connect to GitHub from a Jenkins slave via Git Bash without it asking for credentials?

Comment: You need to install ssh key for Jenkins

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314760/managing-ssh-keys-within-jenkins-for-git

Comment: This solution is for linux. I will be hitting github from a windows command prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a browse around and managed to find my answer. It is solved by the following post

[Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)

Works a treat!!

Answer (score 0):

See Git Bash at https://msysgit.github.io

It's a Linux-like console for Windows.

You will need to generate SSH keys which will be in your `HOME_DIR/.ssh` folder.

As an example, see *[Working with Git on Windows](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html)*.

After generating keys, install it to the GitHub account.