# How to add ssh key from git to Jenkins?

Tags: git, ubuntu, jenkins, ssh

I'm trying to setup new jenkins project on local machine, I have added bitbucket repo in `Source Code Management` section under `Git Repositories`

But I get an error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://git@<main_link>/<name1>/<name2>.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Howewer I can run this command from my console (also I can do `git clone` etc.)

I tried to add ssh key via `Add Credentials` with option `Private Key - Enter directly`

As I understand my private key is under `~/.ssh/`

```
ls ~/.ssh/
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

but after I have entered private ssh key from `~/.ssh/id_dsa` nothing changed, I still get the error.

**Update:**
Tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15314910/1179925

```
sudo -i -u jenkins
jenkins@user-VirtualBox:~$ git clone ssh://git@<link>/<name1>/<name2>.git
Cloning into '<name2>'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Have you checked this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314760/managing-ssh-keys-within-jenkins-for-git

Comment: That is expected: you are using Jenkins account while your keys are in your account.

Comment: @VonC yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is following:

```
#Switch to jenkins user
sudo -i -u jenkins

#Get public key
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

#Add public key for jenkins in github\bitbucket web interface.
```

not sure on which step jenkins generate it's key, but in my case it was already there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Jenkins is running with your account (or its `%HOME%/.ssh` would not be yours)

Also, you can reference your private key with the [SSH Jenkins Credential plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin) (based on [Jenkins Credential Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin)), and use that credential (ie that specific private key) in your Jenkins job setting.